# Tomcat : is it safe to do a rm -r ROOT?

Tags: apache, tomcat, war

I use three different servers with exactly the same configuration.
I tried to deploy a WAR filehave some problems on Tomcat.

A friend told me that it could a problem of war deployment on tomcat

I've tried a shutdown and restart but I still have the same problem.

My next option was to try to do:

```
rm -r webapps/ROOT
```

but I 'm not sure it's completely safe. Is it ok to do so?

Answer (score 1):

**What Documents Says:**

> The ROOT web application presents a very low security risk but it does
>   include the version of Tomcat that is being used. The ROOT web
>   application **should normally be removed** from a publicly accessible
>   Tomcat instance, not for security reasons, but so that a more
>   appropriate default page is shown to users

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html

---

**Specific Answer to your question:**

- **Yes**,you can remove it without facing any problem as you can both leave it removed or
  if you want, you can replace it with a custom default page for your users.